# PHP query to MYSQL with no working ELSE options in WHERE 

Tags: php, mysql, select

My script is prepared for the checkbox answers, but I would also want to if none of the checkbox with instruktor or with instruktor_poczatkowy etc. to select whole column and in case of select some options to do only this options.

```
$dbr = dbq("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE instruktor LIKE '%' OR instruktor in ('$instruktor1', '$instruktor2', '$instruktor3', '$instruktor4',
                           '$instruktor5', '$instruktor6', '$instruktor7', '$instruktor8', '$instruktor9', '$instruktor10', '$instruktor11', '$instruktor12')
                            AND instruktor_poczatkowy in ('$instruktor_poczatkowy1', '$instruktor_poczatkowy2',
                           '$instruktor_poczatkowy3', '$instruktor_poczatkowy4', '$instruktor_poczatkowy5', '$instruktor_poczatkowy6',
                           '$instruktor_poczatkowy7', '$instruktor_poczatkowy8', '$instruktor_poczatkowy9', '$instruktor_poczatkowy10',
                           '$instruktor_poczatkowy11', '$instruktor_poczatkowy12') AND lokalizacja in ('$lokalizacja1','$lokalizacja2', '$lokalizacja3',  '$lokalizacja4', '$lokalizacja5')
                            AND status in ('$status1', '$status2', '$status3', '$status4')
AND chce_mail like '$chce_mail2' AND klub like '$klub2' order by nazwisko");
```

I would like it to work like:

```
        $dbr = dbq("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE instruktor LIKE '%' OR instruktor in ('$instruktor1', '$instruktor2', '$instruktor3', '$instruktor4',
                           '$instruktor5', '$instruktor6', '$instruktor7', '$instruktor8', '$instruktor9', '$instruktor10', '$instruktor11', '$instruktor12')
                           ELSE instruktor = % AND instruktor_poczatkowy in ('$instruktor_poczatkowy1', '$instruktor_poczatkowy2',
                           '$instruktor_poczatkowy3', '$instruktor_poczatkowy4', '$instruktor_poczatkowy5', '$instruktor_poczatkowy6',
                           '$instruktor_poczatkowy7', '$instruktor_poczatkowy8', '$instruktor_poczatkowy9', '$instruktor_poczatkowy10',
                           '$instruktor_poczatkowy11', '$instruktor_poczatkowy12') ELSE instruktor_poczatkowy = % AND lokalizacja in ('$lokalizacja1','$lokalizacja2', '$lokalizacja3',  '$lokalizacja4', '$lokalizacja5')
                           ELSE lokalizacja = % AND status in ('$status1', '$status2', '$status3', '$status4') ELSE status = %
AND chce_mail like '$chce_mail2' AND klub like '$klub2' order by nazwisko");
```

but don't no the way to do it... can someone give me an advice?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` in that way, it's just saying `LIKE` anything, which is the same as not putting it there in the first place.

Comment: `chce_mail like '$chce_mail2' AND klub like '$klub2'` should be `chce_mail like '%$chce_mail2%' AND klub like '%$klub2%'`

Comment: this LIKE is working, but  in other my case where i have testing "ELSE" the code LIKE is warking always showing me everything... no matter is sobe checkbox are selected or not...

Comment: How can i select all without LIKE?

Answer (score 0):

```
LIKE '%'
```

This means that your value can be anything, which is always true (except when your value is null I suppose)

```
LIKE 'foo'
```

This means your value is exactly 'foo'

```
LIKE '%foo'
```

This means that your value ends with 'foo'

```
LIKE 'foo%'
```

This means that your value starts with 'foo'

```
LIKE '%foo%'
```

This means that your value contains 'foo'

Comment: Bear in mind that MySQL pattern matching is case insensitive by default.

Comment: I want to have USE this LIKE as SELECT ALL. and how to write in this query: IF status in ('$status1', '$status2', '$status3', '$status4') NOT selected THAN "select all" status in my table and go to check is more data from my checkbox isn't checked

Comment: If you want to select rows when all of a, b, c, d, e are true then use the OR operator.

Comment: @eggyal, yes, it is. If he/she wants case insensitive behavior then the proper functions are needed indeed.

Comment: but when I'm using "OR instruktor LIKE ='%'" in other case "OR instruktor != 0" after the  It will ALWAYS showing me this second options ignoring this "instruktor in ($instruktor1', '$instruktor2', '$instruktor3',)" is there the other way to do it?

Comment: LIKE '%' means anything, it's normal to ignore the other operands of the OR. Read Sabdeep Bansal's comment.

Comment: is there any other way to replace LIKE string and select all but keep in my the other variables?

Comment: What other variables are you talking about? I'm seeing only two queries in your question. What do you want exactly? If you want to select all except some cases then in your where you should have this kind of logic: where (not (foo)) OR (not (bar)) OR... I'm sorry, but your question is unclear. I don't know what are those checkboxes you are talking about, for instance.